# how do i get "long" content out of the chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

The Chrome debugger is generally quite nice.  However, with "long" content, I'm not sure what options I have to read the content.  In the network window, I get a really long scroll bar.  In the script window, my content is truncated with an ellipsis.

Anyone have secrets for how to get long lines of content out of the debugger?

My understanding is that the debugger is just a special web page.  Is this true?  Can I write scripts to extend the debugger, to myself get content out?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a watch for the variable for which you are trying to get the value, you can then right-click -> Inspect Element on the value that comes up in the watch window. The span that you are then looking at (in the second Developer Tools window) will have the full value.